# вернуть из модуля объект по его имени

Tags: javascript

подскажите плиз: есть модуль с объектами , который подключен к js файлу

```
var obj1 = {
    /* some other props */
};
var obj2 = {
    /* some other props */
};


/**
 * @param {String} objName
 * @returns {Object} 
 */
module.exports = function (objName) {
    //var obj = new Object(objName);
    return obj;
};
```

в js файле пишу так

```
var obj = require('./moduleName.js');
var obj1 = obj('obj1');
```

пока что смог вернуть объект из модуля только так

```
module.exports = function (objName) {
    var obj;
    switch (objName) {
        case 'obj1':
            obj = new Object(obj1);
            break;
    }
    return obj;
};
```

как правильно вернуть объект из модуля используя что то подобное `var obj = new Object(objName);`

Comment: А зачем там обязательно метод возвращается? Может достаточно возвращать объект, в котором перечислены все объекты модуля (контекст)? Или изначальные объекты вверху записывать не в переменные, а в ключи объекта, и потом просто по ключу их брать, а не в кейсе перечислять.

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev простои пример можно ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример:

```
let context = {
obj1: {},
obj2: {}
};
module.exports = context;
```

А если нужен именно метод, то:

```
module.exports = name => context[name];
```

Comment: да , спасибо , решило проблему !!!